# I need a plunger! Where can I get one?

Tags: psychonauts

I'm currently playing though the Milkman level of Psychonauts, and have found the sign and the flowers and the book.

Now I have to find a way into the sewers, and judging by the appearance of these sanitation engineers, I'll need a plunger:

[image: plungers and sewers]

The problem is, I'm sure I've searched all the houses and every fridge I can find, and still no plunger! **Where can I obtain a plunger?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plunger is inside the post office.  It's not obvious how to get in.

But you don't need any items.  Just one of your powers.

> You need to trip the alarm to get one of the agents inside to come out.  At that point you can back off, but use Vision/Clairvoyance on the agent as he's going back in.  That will reveal the keycode they are using.  After that, just walk up and use the code yourself.